# Manually adding PDF to iBooks on iOS 6, using Linux

Tags: pdf, books

There's a long story behind using iOS 6, but basically: I have an iPad 2 WiFi, and it's still a pleasure to read on - but performance on iOS 9 is horrendous, so I use iOS 6 thanks to Coolbooter.

I wish to transfer PDFs to the iPad. I previously used iTools for that purpose (3uTools didn't support iOS 6), but have since removed Windows from my system and have Linux alone. I can access the Books directory on the iPad after mounting it using ifuse, and this is what I've figured yet:

PDFs are given a 4-capital-letter code, stored in the Books directory.
In the folder Books/Sync, there is a Books.plist that contains book metadata, this 4-letter-code, and a Persistence ID (some kind of hash).
In the folder Books/Sync/Database, there is an SQLite database OutstandingAssets_4.sqlite - not sure what Outstanding Assets are, but this database has a table which contains the Persistence IDs of all PDFs I've added (using iTools), and their sizes (which however differ from the original size of the PDFs dropped onto the device).

I tried just pasting the PDF without any modifications onto the Books folder - iBooks didn't read that.
**What exactly should I do to add it properly - how should the PList and DB be modified? How particularly do I get the 4-letter-code and the Persistence ID, and would adding corresponding entries be enough?**

*Note on why jailbreak and iOS 6: frequent crashes on iOS 9, and stuttering for eyecandy that isn't very appealing either. Since the iTunes app no longer had the App Store functionality, and the App Store itself doesn't let you filter apps according to your iOS, as well as for me - not let you download the oldest supported version of an app without having purchased it first, it was frustrating there. On iOS 6, the App Store doesn't work at all (it worked a few times, I might've been locked out later?), but the device is usable. Even Cydia has issues on such an old OS, but at least DEBs and IPAs can be found and dropped on.*

Comment: Somewhat related: I am now using iOS 9. On it, none of this data is necessary. Can just add Title, Author, File to the end of Books/Purchases/Purchases.plist, copy over the file and it shows up (for PDFs). Neat!